# retrieving the last value in a text file and allowing user to reuse it to make new cal

Tags: python

I am working on trying to retrieve the last value in a text file that`s storing all calculations made by user, the user will be able to use the last value in the text file again in a new calculation but when it comes to that part i am not sure how to get it to work.Thanks

```py
question = input("type yes to reuse your calculation !: ")
operator = input("please choose a operator: ")
num2 = float(input("please choose second number: "))

try:

    if "yes" in question:
      with open("file.txt", "r") as t:
        x = t.readlines()[-1].split()
        print(x[-1])
        t.close()
except:
    print("thats wrong")
finally:
    print("Have a great day")
```

example: 200+200 = 400, 400 + 200 = 600
user reuses the last value then gets prompted to enter second number and operator to create new answer

```
600.0 + 400.0 = 1000.0
1000.0 + 200.0 = 1200.0
500.0 + 300.0 = 800.0
```

file.txt would look like this

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: ...and also, can you provide an example of a user's input and just what result you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eval` to calculate the value from a string. Details of `eval` built-in function can be found [in the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Suppose initially we have a file `file.txt` with the following content:

```
200+200 = 400
```

We can do these steps:

1. Get the new operator and operand from the user.
2. Read the last value from the file.
3. Create a string with user input, operator.
4. Calculate new value from the string using `eval` function.
5. Create a new line with user input, operator and the calculated value
6. Finally we can append this new line to the existing `file.txt` file.

`code.py`

```
question = input("type yes to reuse your calculation !: ")
operator = input("please choose a operator: ")
num2 = input("please choose second number: ")
try:
    if "yes" in question:
        old_value = None
        with open("file.txt", "r") as t:
            x = t.readlines()[-1].split()
            old_value = x[-1].strip()
            t.close()
        if old_value:
            new_operation = old_value + operator + num2
            new_value = eval(new_operation)
            new_line = new_operation +" = "+ str(new_value)+"\n"
            print(new_line)
            with open("file.txt", "a") as myfile:
                myfile.write(new_line)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    print("thats wrong")
finally:
    print("Have a great day")
```

Running the code:

```
type yes to reuse your calculation !: yes
please choose a operator: -
please choose second number: 100
400-100 = 300

Have a great day
```

Updated `file.txt`:

```
200+200 = 400
400-100 = 300
```